# Third-Party WSDL method, doesn't work and don't return any error

Tags: c#, web-services, wsdl

I'm using a third party wsdl and sometimes a specifc method doesn't work (value not sent), and i can't get any error. The basic of code:

```
try
{
    ret = ANASrv.InsertMeasurement(lguser, lgpass, estacoes.ToArray());

    //evaluate error
    if (ret.qtdInserted== 1)
    {
        WriteLog("Measurement Inserted Sucessfully");
    }
    else
    {
        WriteLog("Insert Failed");
        WriteLog("Code error: " + ret.message[0]);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    WriteLog("Any other error");
}
```

The question is, sometimes, the InsertMeasurement doesn't work and the catch Execption not executed.
What can I do to capture any error in these situations?

Comment: An exception can only be caught once unless a THROW is used where it is captured.  If InsertMeasurement contains an exception handler (or a library) you will not be able to capture the exception in your code.